# Infinitely looping through a recordset in VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, dao, ms-access-2010

I've got a recordset I'm looping through using .movenext and all, but it always loops around!

```
Dim dbsNu As Database
Dim rsNieuw As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsOld As DAO.Recordset

        Set rsOld = dbsNu.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblActieElementLink WHERE actieElement = " & Me.actieElementId, dbOpenDynaset)
        Set rsNieuw = dbsNu.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblActieElementLink", dbOpenDynaset)

        With rsNieuw

            Do While rsOld.EOF = False

                .AddNew
                    !actieElement = rsOld!actieElement
                .Update

                rsOld.MoveNext
            Loop
```

rsOld.EOF is never true, and it keeps on adding new records.

Comment: what do you see in debug? especially the `rsOld` var

Comment: Oh, that's the problem. I thought rsold was a snapshop, but I kept adding data to it so it kept looping.

Comment: so your problem is solved? :)

Comment: If you solved the problem, you should enter your answer below and mark it as "solved" even if you answered it yourself :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought rsOld was a snapshot, but because I kept adding records to the same table through rsNieuw it got stuck in an infinite loop.